# What is the Rate of change of f (x^2) given rate of change of f (x)

Tags: calculus

Find the average rate of change of $f(x^2)$ on the interval [1,4] given that  the average rate of change of $f (x)$ equals 9
on  interval [1,16]?

This question  has two different "answers" according  to  two different  teachers

The first  give answer of 9 by assuming $y=x^2$ and applying the formula  of rate of change as following 
Let$ y=x^2 $ with $I$= [1,4] then$ f (1)$=1,$f (4)$=16

$\frac{f(4^2) - f(1^2)}{(4^2 -1^2)}$  = 
$\frac{f (y_{2})-f (y_{1})}{y_{2}-y_{1}}$
 =
$\frac{f(16) - f(1)}{(16-1)}$ =9

The second give the answer of 45 
as following

$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{(b - a)}$ to $\frac{f(16) - f(1)}{16 - 1}=9$ to

$\frac{f(16) - f(1)}{15}=9$

$f(16) - f(1)=9*15$
Now  we find rate of change of $f (x^2)$ following 
$\frac{f(16) - f(1)}{4 - 1}=\frac{9*15}{3}=45$
what is
the  right  answer?
Can we ensure  the either answers geometrically? 
Thank you for helping

Comment: Can you show the first answer ?

Comment: I don't get what do you mean by  " applying the formula of rate of change" ? It means taking derivative ? isn't it $f^{'} (x^2) = 2xf^{'}(x^2) = 18x$ ? how do you get $9$ here ?

Comment: How $\frac{f(16) - f(1)}{(16-1)} = 9$ ? Do you know the value of $f(1), f(16)$ ?

Comment: @A---B   no i don't  , i just have the averge rate of change  on the interval

Comment: The first answer is not correct because we are calculating the average of $f(x^2)$ with respect to a change in $x$, or with your substitution $x^2=y$, the average of $f(y)$ with respect to a change in $\color{red}{\sqrt{y}}$.

Comment: @amWhy Yes my bad. Since OP was making so many edits I got confused. Still the first answer is incorrect.

Comment: What you found in the latter part of your post is correct, wrt the average rate of change of $f(x^2)$ over $x \in [1, 16]$, and having used some of the information you were given about the average rate of change of $f(x)$ over the interval $x\in [1, 16]$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) = f(x^2)$.

The average rate of change of a function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is $\dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.

The average rate of change of $f$ on the interval $[1,16]$ is $$\frac{f(16) - f(1)}{16 - 1} = \frac{f(16) - f(1)}{15}.$$

You are told this rate of change equals $9$.

The average rate of change of $g$ on the interval $[1,4]$ is thus equal to $$ \frac{g(4) - g(1)}{4-1} = \frac{f(16) - f(1)}{3} = 5 \cdot \frac{f(16) - f(1)}{15} = 45.$$

Comment: Why did you not simply comment to confirm the askers work, who has done all the work, and arrived at the same answer as you, 47 minutes ago, so much prior to your answer.  Why not, at least, acknowledge that the asker is correct, in your answer?

Comment: @Umberto P. What is wrong  in this       $\frac{f(4^2) - f(1^2)}{(4^2 -1^2)}$  = 
$\frac{f (y_{2})-f (y_{1})}{y_{2}-y_{1}}$
 =
$\frac{f(16) - f(1)}{(16-1)}$ =9     after asumming $y = x^2$

Comment: @prayersmith It is wrt to $x^2$ you are told to find wrt $x$.